# Google Sheet formulation

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, formula, vlookup

I am trying something on Google Sheets and I need some help.

The issue is, I have two sub-sheets, one with a long list of details regarding potential participants named "Confirmed Participants" and the other with a list of events with their participation named "Agenda".

Now what I am trying to do is, I am trying to include a column in "Confirmed Participants" where the event name from "Agenda" would be displayed depending on their choice of participation.

The sheet "Agenda" has the names of the participants and their details in each cell. While the sheet "Confirmed Participants" have only their names.

The closest I could get to solving the issue was the formula =INDEX(lookup_array, MATCH(lookup_value, search_array, FALSE))

but this seems to show me an error. Can anyone help me edit this formula to get what i want?

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  This should show the original (sample) data with the desired results entered manually.  Help others help you.

Comment: Filter would probably work, but it's hard to tell exactly what you're doing.  Use a [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to show a sample of your two sheets, and then one more table to show the desired outcome.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lBTQRLqKPM4xHfj05iXARZA69WRNflt3YSAYcJUqZBw/edit#gid=1329217189

This is a sample sheet with the details. The yellow highlighted is the manually inputted data. I want the formula for the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(B2:B,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,join(", ",ifna(filter(Agenda!E:E,regexmatch(Agenda!D:D,Σ)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you.